# Bootstrap layout: Img nested inside a div won't align left edges

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap container with an img inside. I'd expect the left side of the image to align
with the LHS of the container. Looking through the CSS with the browser debugger doesn't show any margin, border, etc that seems to be responsible. Playing with position and align doesn't fix this issue.

I can force it by styling the img with "margin-left:-15px".

I'd really like to know why this isn't working as I'd expect and where does the 15 pixel magic number come from.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Could you please share CSS and HTML for clarification.

Comment: <div class="container"> <img src="logo.png"></div>  The logo will be inset by 15px. Why?

Answer (score 0):

@joe McGuckin. The magic number comes from the bootstrap template css file. Here is the snapshot from Bootstrap.min file.

[image: Snapshot of Bootstrap Main CSS file]

Bootstrap is a frame work which provides some built in elements to make a page responsive. Please refer to the bootstrap documentation for guidance.

Comment: Would appreciate if you vote and provide your feedback regarding my answer. Was it useful or not?